# Pass parameters to HttpPost method of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-mvc-controller

There something very basic i must be missing which i cant understand what it is.
I have a method at the controller

```
    [Route("SomeMethod")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SomeMethod([FromBody]int interval)
    {
        ...
    }
```

And im seing with postman post request `{"interval": 2000 }`, The interval at the controller is not initialized. If i change the method paramater to be object i get `ValueKind = Object : "{"interval": 2000 }"`

I also tried the parameter to be string and then the body i sent is `{"interval": "2000" }`, And at the controller i get null

Based on this question i tried:

```
[Route("SomeMethod")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SomeMethod([FromBody]JsonElement interval)
{
    ...
}
```

And got `ValueKind = Undefined : ""` At the contoroller, And also:

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

When the method expects an int and got 0

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) you have to pass it in request body as it is, just a value, without property name. But its imposible to bind more then one parameter. Anyway, I would reccomend to use proper object to bind body parameters.

```
[Route("SomeMethod")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SomeMethod([FromBody]Request request)
{
    return Ok();
}


public class Request
{
    public int Interval { get; set; }
}
```